# boost::log save message in container and then send all messages to backend

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I want to save actual formatted message in memory with something like `memory_sink` and then on `flush` send messages in backend. But there is a problem, that attributes of saved `record_view` are changed to the attributes of the last created `record_view`, I have no idea why such behaviour is. But probably someone can say me, can I implement something like I want, or not?

Really minimal example:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DLL 1
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/keyword.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#undef BOOST_LOG_DLL

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <queue>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

typedef sinks::combine_requirements<sinks::synchronized_feeding, sinks::flushing>::type sync_flushing;

struct message_t
{
   message_t(const logging::record_view& r, const std::string& f) :
      record(r), fstring(f)
   {
   }
   logging::record_view record;
   std::string fstring;
};

template<typename Sink>
class memory_sink : public sinks::basic_formatted_sink_backend<char, sync_flushing>
{
public:
   memory_sink(const boost::shared_ptr<Sink>& sink) : sink_(sink)
   {
   }

   void consume(const logging::record_view& rec, const string_type& fstring)
   {
      const message_t msg(rec, fstring);
      messages_.push(msg);
   }

   void flush()
   {
      while (!messages_.empty())
      {
         const message_t& msg = messages_.front();
         sink_->consume(msg.record, msg.fstring);
         messages_.pop();
      }
   }
private:
   typedef std::queue<message_t> buffer_t;
   buffer_t messages_;
   const boost::shared_ptr<Sink> sink_;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, logging::trivial::severity_level lvl)
{
   return stream << boost::log::trivial::to_string(lvl);
}

class cout_sink : public sinks::basic_formatted_sink_backend< char, sinks::synchronized_feeding >
{
public:
   std::string format(const logging::record_view& rec, const std::string& fstring) const
   {
      return fstring;
   }
   void consume(const logging::record_view& rec, const std::string& fstring)
   {
      std::cout << "[" << rec[boost::log::trivial::severity] << "] " << fstring << std::endl;
   }
};

void init_cout()
{
   typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<memory_sink<cout_sink> > sink_t;

   boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();
   core->remove_all_sinks();

   boost::shared_ptr< cout_sink > tsink = boost::make_shared<cout_sink>();
   boost::shared_ptr<memory_sink<cout_sink> > backend = boost::make_shared<memory_sink<cout_sink> >(tsink);
   boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink = boost::make_shared<sink_t>(tsink);

   core->add_sink(sink);
}

void flush_logs()
{
   logging::core::get()->flush();
}

int main()
{
   logging::add_common_attributes();
   init_cout();
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "warning message";
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "error message";
   flush_logs();
}
```

[Live version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5ffb30df205b3d3)

As you can see severity in both record is `error`, but I expect `warning` and `error`. Probably there is better way to do this?

I know about formatter, here severity is printed in `backend`, only for example, since real code is bigger and sinks on consume receives `record_view`, than just send it to backend, that also receives only `record_view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observe is caused by an optimization technique used by the library. When creating a log record, Boost.Log can sometimes avoid copying attribute values into the record by referencing thread-specific data that holds the original values. Thread-specific data is supposed to stay constant while the record is being processed. Asynchronous sinks, which obviously need to pass records between threads, have a way to communicate that to the logging core, so that this optimization is disabled and log records are detached from the originating thread before passing to the sink. This is described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/attribute_value.html), see the note about `detach_from_thread`.

The problem is that only the sink frontend decides whether this optimization has to be disabled, and only the `asynchronous_sink` does that. There is no way to customize that for other frontends. So either you have to use your backend with `asynchronous_sink` or you have to write your frontend as well.

To implement a sink frontend you need a class that derives from the [`sink`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/sink.html) base class and performs filtering, formatting (if needed) and passes the record to the backend. You can use `synchronous_sink` implementation as an example. The important difference from `synchronous_sink` is that you have to pass `true` to the `sink` constructor. This will tell the logging core that your sink requires detached log records.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Will try that. However, how do you think, is `memory_sink` good way to implement what I want, or probably I should do something, when I add attributes to record?

Comment: I don't know what problem you are solving with `memory_sink` but personally I would try to avoid buffering records. Not only it tends to grow memory consumption of your app, it also reduces reliability and performance - the `detach_from_thread` method I mentioned can be rather expensive. If your real sink that you feed in `memory_sink` tends to block and that is what you're trying to mitigate then you're probably better off with async logging.

Comment: Problem, that I want to solve is just send messages in actual backend only when there are max messages, or flush function is called. So, I need store records with attributes (like severity/facility/time/line/file) somewhere, `memory_sink` was for these. But probably I should just store list of attributes and messages and construct record just before sending...

Comment: And one more question, now about `async_frontend`, why only this frontend has `stop` function? And why there is no some base `async_frontend` with `stop` function, that is not templated? It's very hard to write function, that returns all possible sinks for stop call.

Comment: The `stop` function breaks the `run` loop which no other sink has. No other frontends have a dedicated processing thread, so no `stop` needed.